# RewriteRule with optional params

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have been trying for several hours to modify a URL by including optional parameters

My rewriting rules do not work

It consists of an ID, a slug and the two optional parameters are "-season- {number} -" and "-episode -" {number} "

I think the problem is that the slug sometimes contains a dash at the end.

```
RewriteRule ^serie-([0-9]+)(-([a-z0-9/-]))? serie.php?id=$1&sl=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^serie-([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9/-])-saison-([0-9]+)-episode-([0-9]+)$ /serie.php?id=$1&sl=$2&esid=S$3-E$4 [L]
```

I want this result:

```
serie-1-the-strain
```

and with optional params:

```
serie-1-the-strain-saison-17-episode-259
```

Thanks or your help!

Comment: Please provide some examples of URLs, both matching and not yet matching ones

Comment: Ok, thanks i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update the `RewriteRule` as:

```
RewriteRule ^serie-([0-9]+)-([a-z0-9/-]+)-saison-([0-9]+)-episode-([0-9]+)$ /serie.php?id=$1&sl=$2&esid=S$3-E$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^serie-([0-9]+)(-([a-z0-9/-]+))? serie.php?id=$1&sl=$3 [L]
```